I have played a gambit-like game, and don't know it's unique one or not
I am a 1200+ rated player from Bangladesh. I played against a Burmese (from Myanmar) player today who is also 1200+ rated. The game lasted 12 moves, and it felt like a gambit. I have never seen a gambit like it.
Do you know whether it's an unique gambit or not?
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2024.12.27"]
[Round "?"]
[White "mqraiyun"]
[Black "KominMyanmar"]
[Result "1-0"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[WhiteElo "1244"]
[BlackElo "1219"]
[Termination "mqraiyun won by resignation"]
[ECO "A00"]
[EndTime "12:40:46 GMT+0000"]
[FEN ""]

1. e3 c5 2. d4 cxd4 3. exd4 Nc6 4. d5 Ne5 5. c4 d6 6. Bf4 f6 7. Bxe5 dxe5 8. Nf3 Bg4 9. Be2 e4 10. Ne5 Bxe2 11. Qa4+ b5 12. Qxb5+ 1-0


I'm not seeing any gambit here, and there really isn't much theory on 1. e3.

Almost certainly unique, with 1.e3 and the odd 6...f6. But hard to prove that.

The closest game that I could find was https://lichess.org/O6r6YnN9
The game, although starting with a different move order, reaches the same position after 8 moves from both sides. The ninth move from White, Be2, seems to be a first, which I couldn't find in any of the databases.
The so-called "Gambit", or the Knight sacrifice that you play on move 10 is actually unsound (and the refutation can be found if all checks, captures, and threats are properly analyzed).
The proper continuation might look like:
[FEN ""]

1.e3 c5 2.d4 cxd4 3.exd4 Nc6 4.d5 Ne5 5.c4 d6 6.Bf4 f6 7.Bxe5 dxe5 8.Nf3 Bg4 9.Be2 e4 10.Ne5 Qa5+ *


Qa5+ is the only check in the position for Black, and must be evaluated. Irrespective of what White does here, the "Gambit" knight can be won, without any significant drawback by Black.

One possible continuation:
[FEN ""]

1.e3 c5 2.d4 cxd4 3.exd4 Nc6 4.d5 Ne5 5.c4 d6 6.Bf4 f6 7.Bxe5 dxe5 8.Nf3 Bg4 9.Be2 e4 10.Ne5 Qa5+ 11. Nc3 Bxe2 12. Qxe2 fxe5 13. Qxe4 g6 14. Qxe5 Nf6 15. O-O *

Although White is down a piece, it has gained two pawns for it, and the game might still be interesting for a wide range of players, except those at the very top.

Yeah! Qa5+ is the only surviving move there, I know too. But many gambits are usually consisted of mistakes, sometimes blunders... It's a trap for the opponent that he needs to check the king with Qa5+ and then take the knight. If not, then mate in 3...
